# Find and draw domain of function $f(x, y) = \ln(x\ln(y-x)).$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

The part that is confusing me I know that $y-x>0$ so $y>x$ and that is first condition. And then second condition is split in two ways (when $x>0$ and when $x<0$). I can't figure why is that.

Comment: That looks like a very good start. The conditions are (first) that $y>x$, and also (second) [ either ($x>0$ and $\ln(y-x)>0$) or ($x<0$ and $\ln(y-x)<0$) ]. The word “and” translates into intersection of sets, and the word “or” translates into union of sets. It should work out.

Comment: @Lubin Ok i got it, when we have x<0 we need to find ln(y-x)<0 because negative number*negative number gives out positive and we can get some result from natural logarithm that way. Example i used is x = -1 y= -0.5 and it goes -1*ln(0.5) > 0 and that is true. Thanks.

Comment: “Get it?” “Got it.” “Good!”